# How can I remove the CSS filter style from text?

Tags: css, filter

I want to remove blur from the text but keep the image in back blurred? How can I achieve that?

[image]

This is the CSS I am using:

```
div.feature-img.page-banner {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
}
```

Page link : http://newinternetdaily.com/2015/12/29/nasa-prepares-modern-telescope/

Is there any way to remove the CSS style from the text?

UPDATE : HTML CODE

```html
<div class="feature-img page-banner" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=1280%2C794);">
    <h1 class="headline img-headline" style="">NASA prepares Modern Telescope</h1>
    <img width="1280" height="794" src="http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=1280%2C794" class="attachment-swell-featured-large size-swell-featured-large wp-post-image" alt="1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg" srcset="http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=300%2C186 300w, http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=768%2C476 768w, http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=1024%2C635 1024w, http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?w=1280 1280w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px">   </div>
```

Comment: You should add the html code to the question

Comment: CSS filters affect all child elements of the parent where the filter has been applied and cannot be overridden...it's like `opacity` in that respect. The text would have be in a completely different, non-child element to the filtered image.

Comment: I would like to be the first to point out the irony that text describing NASA's new telescope is out of focus!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code from:

```
div.feature-img.page-banner {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
}
```

To:

```
div.feature-img.page-banner > img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
}
```

this should work: with the ">" symbol your telling your code just to affect the image.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/soqre770/6/

```css
div.banner > img{
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.banner p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: verdana;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">

<img src="http://resurrection-mn.com/hp_wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Wooden-Texture-Website-Banner.png">

<p>Test Text</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably add img to the element selector

```
div.feature-img.page-banner img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
}
```

Comment: No, this is also not working, i guess the text is child to the the parent image?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
/* Add this class with ::before selector. */
.feature-img.page-banner::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: 0;
    filter: blur(4px);
}
.page-banner, .feature-img.page-banner {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 240px;
    max-height: 640px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;

    /* And add this 2 new lines... */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: @AnkitBagwan I think it works if you remove `filter: blur(4px);` from `div.feature-img.page-banner`.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking off the background image on the wrapper div and use absolute positioning:

```css
 div.feature-img.page-banner img {
   -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
   filter: blur(4px);
   position: absolute;
 }
 .img-headline {
   position: absolute;
   color: white;
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="feature-img page-banner">
  <h1 class="headline img-headline" style="">NASA prepares Modern Telescope</h1>
  <img width="1280" height="794" src="http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=1280%2C794" class="attachment-swell-featured-large size-swell-featured-large wp-post-image">
</div>
```

Comment: i am afraid No luck :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="banner-container">
<div class="feature-img page-banner" style="background-image: url(http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=1280%2C794);">
    <img width="1280" height="794" src="http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=1280%2C794" class="attachment-swell-featured-large size-swell-featured-large wp-post-image" alt="1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg" srcset="http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=300%2C186 300w, http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=768%2C476 768w, http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?resize=1024%2C635 1024w, http://i1.wp.com/newinternetdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1280px-james_webb_telescope_model_at_south_by_southwest.jpg?w=1280 1280w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px">   </div>
    </div>
<h1 class="headline img-headline" style="">NASA prepares Modern Telescope</h1>
</div>

<style>
.banner-container {
display: block;
position: relative;
}
div.feature-img.page-banner {
display: block;
-webkit-filter: blur(4px);
filter: blur(4px);
}
.img-headline {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 20;
color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I think this works. Can't see any blur myself though. Give it a whirl

Comment: please can you tell what changes you made?

Comment: I added a container div (class="banner-container") and moved the h1 tag outside of the page banner div. So now they are two separate divs inside a container div. The container div will stretch to fit the size of the image div within and the h1 now has position absolute so it will appear on top of the image. As the blur is applied to the image div, it no longer affects the text.